# Combine 2 lists with diff shapes while having values to link them like a data frame Python

Tags: python, dataframe, similarity

I have list number 1:

```
['Limitation', 'Parameter', 'input', 'Feature', 'Dataset', 'Output', 'EvaluationMetric', 'Algorithm', 'Task', 'HyperParameter', 'Layer', 'Model', 'Operator', 'Function', 'OptimizationAlgorithm', 'ActivationFunction', 'LeakyReluFunction', 'LossFunction']
```

list number2:

```
['Input', 'Dataset', 'Algorithm', 'Operator', 'Task', 'HyperParameter', 'Output']
```

And I have these values that describe the similarity between these words
and how could I make a data frame. that contains rows as the first list strings, columns as the sec list, and the values in the cells

```
0.4
0.75
0.75
0.65
0.65
0.050000000000000044
0.25
0.25
0.5
0.6
0.75
0.7
0.75
1.0
0.75
0.4
0.6
0.75
0.5
0.75
0.7
0.65
0.6
0.09999999999999998
0.25
0.30000000000000004
0.44999999999999996
0.55
0.6
0.6
0.55
0.6
0.6
0.35
1.0
0.55
0.4
0.6
0.6
0.65
0.6
0.4
0.25
0.25
0.44999999999999996
0.65
0.7
0.65
0.75
0.65
0.7
0.4
0.65
0.65
0.6
0.7
0.6
1.0
0.65
0.25
0.25
0.30000000000000004
0.5
0.55
0.6
0.75
0.7
0.75
0.7
0.25
0.55
1.0
0.35
0.8
0.75
0.65
0.6
0.0
0.15000000000000002
0.19999999999999996
0.44999999999999996
0.35
0.75
0.4
0.44999999999999996
0.5
0.35
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.35
1.0
0.44999999999999996
0.35
0.6
0.30000000000000004
0.050000000000000044
0.15000000000000002
0.25
0.30000000000000004
0.55
0.6
0.85
0.7
0.75
1.0
0.35
0.6
0.7
0.35
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.09999999999999998
0.25
0.25
0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data have 117 values, and you have a 18x7 matrix (rows*columns) that requires 126 values.. filling this with NaN you could

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


your_data = '0.4 0.75 0.75 0.65 0.65 0.050000000000000044 0.25 0.25 0.5 0.6 0.75 0.7 0.75 1.0 0.75 0.4 0.6 0.75 0.5 0.75 0.7 0.65 0.6 0.09999999999999998 0.25 0.30000000000000004 0.44999999999999996 0.55 0.6 0.6 0.55 0.6 0.6 0.35 1.0 0.55 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.65 0.6 0.4 0.25 0.25 0.44999999999999996 0.65 0.7 0.65 0.75 0.65 0.7 0.4 0.65 0.65 0.6 0.7 0.6 1.0 0.65 0.25 0.25 0.30000000000000004 0.5 0.55 0.6 0.75 0.7 0.75 0.7 0.25 0.55 1.0 0.35 0.8 0.75 0.65 0.6 0.0 0.15000000000000002 0.19999999999999996 0.44999999999999996 0.35 0.75 0.4 0.44999999999999996 0.5 0.35 0.30000000000000004 0.4 0.35 1.0 0.44999999999999996 0.35 0.6 0.30000000000000004 0.050000000000000044 0.15000000000000002 0.25 0.30000000000000004 0.55 0.6 0.85 0.7 0.75 1.0 0.35 0.6 0.7 0.35 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.09999999999999998 0.25 0.25 0.5'
values = your_data.split(' ')

for i in range(9):
    values.append(np.nan)

data_matrix = np.split(np.array(values), (18))


list1 = ['Limitation', 'Parameter', 'input', 'Feature', 'Dataset', 'Output', 'EvaluationMetric', 'Algorithm', 'Task', 'HyperParameter', 'Layer', 'Model', 'Operator', 'Function', 'OptimizationAlgorithm', 'ActivationFunction', 'LeakyReluFunction', 'LossFunction']

list2 =['Input', 'Dataset', 'Algorithm', 'Operator', 'Task', 'HyperParameter', 'Output']

df = pd.DataFrame(index=list1, columns=list2, data=data_matrix)
print(df)
```

Comment: Would [pd.crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab) be useful here?